# Vertical position of text in <div>

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm newbie, so probably question may sound stupid. Sorry for that. But I fight this small problem for whole day.

I have a student project:

https://codepen.io/kremlevmax/pen/EomEyb

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="menu-bar">
<button href="#" class="btn menu-button">Test Button</button>
      <button href="#" class="btn menu-button">Test Button</button>
      <button href="#" class="btn menu-button">Test Button</button>
</div>
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3">
            <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/dB3Dvgf3VIglusoGJAfpNUAANhTXW8K9mvIsiIPkhJUAbAKGKJcEMPTf0mkSexzLM5o=w300" class="portfolio-photo">
            </div>
          <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-9 div-photo-text">
            <p class="text">
              Some test text
              </div>
            </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: #C0F2FB;
  font-family: "Tahoma";
  margin: 0;
}

.outer {
  background-color: #E8F8FA;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.inner {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 94%;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  margin: 70px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.portfolio-photo {
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 4px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.div-photo-text {
  padding: 50%;
  text-align: left;
}
.text {
  font-size: 120%;
}


.menu-bar {
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0; 
  width: 100%; 
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #1A899D;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.menu-button {
  float: right;
  background-color: #1A899D;
  border: 2px solid #1A899D;
  color: #C0F2FB;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.menu-button:hover {
  background-color: #C0F2FB;
  color: #000000;
}
```

So there are three questions actually:

1. Why "Some test text" isn't vertically centered in div, which one is to
   the right from picture?
2. Why during scrolling picture and text goes over menu and not under?
3. If I delete padding in div-photo-text class "Some test text" moves under image, but why? Shouldn't col-lg-3 and col-lg-9 move div with text next to div with image?

Thanks for any kind of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Max For the first question, you need to remove the 50% padding because it is giving padding in all directions and add the vertical alignment and horizontal alignment.

```
//Vertical
.vertical-align {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

//Horizantal
.text {
  text-align: center;
}
```

For the 2nd question, you just need to add `z-index:1` to your menu for it to be come over your text. The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element. An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.

For the 3rd question, its coming like that because you missed the below div which is required when using bootstrap row grids, you need to add this to parent div of text and image to tell the page they should be in one row.

```
<div class="row">

</div>
```

check the code here :: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GymbVJ

Comment: Thanks, Kumar! You saved me. All the best for you.

Comment: You are welcome Max. If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). It lets everyone know that this is the answer for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
body {
  background-color: #C0F2FB;
  font-family: "Tahoma";
  margin: 0;
}

.outer {
  background-color: #E8F8FA;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.inner {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 94%;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.portfolio-photo {
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 4px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.div-photo-text {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: left;
}

.text {
  font-size: 120%;
}

.menu-bar {
  z-index: 1
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0; 
  width: 100%; 
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #1A899D;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.menu-button {
  float: right;
  background-color: #1A899D;
  border: 2px solid #1A899D;
  color: #C0F2FB;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.menu-button:hover {
  background-color: #C0F2FB;
  color: #000000;
}
.row{
  display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
    <div class="menu-bar">
<button href="#" class="btn menu-button">Test Button</button>
      <button href="#" class="btn menu-button">Test Button</button>
      <button href="#" class="btn menu-button">Test Button</button>
</div>
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3">
            <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/dB3Dvgf3VIglusoGJAfpNUAANhTXW8K9mvIsiIPkhJUAbAKGKJcEMPTf0mkSexzLM5o=w300" class="portfolio-photo">
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-9 div-photo-text">
            <p class="text">
              Some test text
            </div>
            
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>
```